# Dynamically show a specific number of the fractional part's digits

Tags: function-construction, manipulate, output-formatting

What is the fastest way to cut off all `n  z` digits of the fractional part of a real number?

(For example 12390.20934230)

I came up with this so far:

```
Round[l_List, z_] := 
 IntegerPart[l] + 
   Module[{r = RealDigits[l]},
     Fold[10 #1 + #2 &, 0, Take[r[[1]], {Max[r[[2]],0]+z, r[[2]]+z}]] 10^-z]
```

Best would be a fast pure function to run over an array, and optimal would be to just show the output rounded (aka ScientificForm), but let the actual numbers as they are.

Comment: Perhaps map `ScientificForm` over your array at the -1 level?

Comment: First of all, it does not round the number the way I want it to, second I think after ScientificForm it is no number any more...

Comment: What I suggested does not modify the contents of an array unless you assign the results back to a symbol bound to the array, which I did not suggest. Perhaps mapping `NumberForm` would be more to your liking.

Comment: a) would you like the output to be assignable? that is, do you want to display the number in truncated form, or actually truncate? b) what do you mean "dynamically"? as the question is states, it has nothing to do with `Dynamic` or `Manipulate`. c) you want to run it over an array of what, and to do what? you just need a round function to map over a list of reals? or what?

Comment: Round[x,10^-z] with integer z rounds to z digits. Would that do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to figure out from your question what you want.
You probably can do it with `NumberForm` and its options, so here is an example:

```
nums = 5000^RandomReal[2, 10];      (* make some numbers *)

nums // InputForm                   (* look at the long form *)
```

> ```
> {39753.38655208366, 372163.42335132253, 603781.8781407636, 312.9474417510306,
>  84106.95799695785, 8609.944109613456, 1.2586190926109136*^6,    
>  25203.109639366387, 413952.63700106385, 8.649027381565293}
> ```

Define a formatting function using `NumberForm` and apply it:

```
myForm = 
 NumberForm[#, {6, 3}, ExponentFunction -> (If[# < 6, Null, 3 Quotient[#, 3]] &)] &;

formatted = nums // myForm          (* format the numbers *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
First @ formatted // InputForm      (* prove that the numbers are unchanged *)
```

> ```
> {39753.38655208366, 372163.42335132253, 603781.8781407636, 312.9474417510306,
>  84106.95799695785, 8609.944109613456, 1.2586190926109136*^6,    
>  25203.109639366387, 413952.63700106385, 8.649027381565293}
> ```

Comment: Thank you, next time I will be more precise I promise.